# The path to save the template SSRS Visual Studio 2019

Tags: templates, reporting-services, path

The following path for SSRS templates doesn't work in Visual Studio 2019.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\ProjectItems\ReportProject

Initially the path was not there so  I created one hoping I'll be able to see templates, but it didn't work out. I looked up  this issue and someone suggested the following path instead:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\2019\SQL\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\SSRS\ProjectItems\ReportProject

Still I'm not able to see the SSRS template created.

What's the right location for the templates?

Thank you !

Comment: Check my Answer here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60827012/location-of-configuration-file-used-by-report-wizard-query-builder-to-source-def/60828388#60828388

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\SSRS\ProjectItems\ReportProject

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The location I found my templates in is:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\SSRS\ProjectItems\ReportProject

[DirectorySnippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2hgk.png)